# Choosing Container ports numbers

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-machine

Please see the command below:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password1" -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

After I run this command I can connect to the database using SQL Studio manager as shown below:

[image]

I can also connect using: 192.168.99.100,1433.
Next I remove the container and execute the following command:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password1" -p 600:600 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

I have made up the port here.   Now, please see the screenshot below:

[image]

1)  Why is the tcp port 1433?

2)  Why can I not connect to the database on port 500?

I realise the documentation tells you to use port 1433 as shown here: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/.  However, it does not tell me why.

Comment: Unless I'm reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-linux-2017), and your question, incorrectly, `-p 600:600` would cause the service to run on port `600`, not `500`. Is one a typo?

Comment: @Larnu, yes it is a typo.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The image Dockerfile presumably says `EXPOSE 1433` because that's the port the server listens on; the bare `1433/tcp` output in `docker ps` means that port isn't published to the host.

(2) When you `docker run -p 600:600`, you tell Docker to forward port 600 on the host to port 600 in the container.  Nothing's listening on that port, so you can't connect.

(3) If you `docker run -p 600:1433`, you'd tell Docker to forward port 600 on the host to port 1433 in the container, where the server is listening, and I would expect this to work.

Comment: Thanks.  I tested point three just before you answered and it does work.  I understand now that the SQL Server (inside container) is listening on port 1433 and that is why 600:1433 works.

Comment: With regards to point one.  What do you mean by: "not published to the host"?

Comment: "There is no port you can use on the host's IP address that will forward to the container; the server is only accessible from other Docker containers on the same host and the same Docker network."

Comment: That makes sense +1.  How would I expose the port to the host?

Comment: With `docker run -p`.

Comment: could you have a look at my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465944/cannot-switch-from-linux-container-to-windows-container ?