# Cannot switch from Linux container to Windows container

Tags: .net, docker

I have recently rebuilt my PC from scratch.  I have installed Docker for Windows.  I cannot switch from Linux container to Windows container.  Here is the error I get:

```
Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Docker.Backend.DockerDaemonChecker.Check(Func`1 isDaemonProcessStillRunning) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\DockerDaemonChecker.cs:line 63
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Windows.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Windows.cs:line 218
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Windows.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Windows.cs:line 93
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 46
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 144
```

I have spent all weekend so far trying to get this to work.  I have read many webpages including this one: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1126  Nothing works.  I am using Windows 10 64 Bit.  Linux containers are ok.

I have tried reinstalling Hypervisor.

My Windows 10 version is: 1803.  I wander if there is an issue with this version: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1927

**Update**

I have two Windows PCs:

1) Tablet, which I purchased two years ago - Docker switches to Windows containers correctly.

2) PC, which I rebuilt at the weekend (with a new SSD card).  I have the problem described above with this PC.  I used a Windows 10 CD, which I created in 2015/16 and then applied the automatic updates.

I wander if there is an issue with the updates that were applied to 2?